# RSS feed reader in Android

Tags: android, rss-reader

I am a relative newcomer in Android. I want to make an app which displays different RSS feeds. I have done research on this and the things I have found are overwhelmingly complex. They contain just miles and miles of code. Can someone give me a link to a simplified guide to do this?

Comment: First result on Google: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_rss_reader.htm This doesn't seem that complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start from [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_rss_reader.htm) and modify the code in order to get mutiple sources in order to store the different feeds.

Unfortunately you won't find any less complicated examples, it is a simple app and you don't have a million ways to do it.